# How do I open a terminal tab with an NPM script?

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line, terminal, appium

I would like to automate the testing sequence of my Cordova app.

I know I can run `nom` scripts in sequence by specifying a script name, and then specifying a series of scripts separated by semicolons. This is working perfectly for other parts of my dev environment.

For the UI tests, I'm using Webdriver and Appium. This is the series of scripts I would like to automate, but I can't seem to find out what the commands are to get the specific sequence running (specifically regarding the Appium server):

1) Run jest unit tests (this is not a problem)

2) If jest tests do not fail, start the Appium server in a *new* terminal tab

3) Either wait for a successful signal (not sure what this would be) that the Appium server has started or set a reasonable timeout

4) Run the UI tests with WebDriver/Mocha (this is also not a problem running by itself).

5) Kill the Appium server

Part 3 is my hurdle, specifically how to get the Appium started in a separate terminal tab. Chaining these together would be great.

The goal here is to automate the entire testing series in something like `npm run allTheTests` so I can leave and get a sandwich, send a text, read a Medium article (etc.) while the tests complete.

Many thanks =)

Comment: I don't know anything about Appium, but it strikes me that what you might really want here is to start it in a *separate process*, rather than a new *terminal tab*?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks for the comment- you can probably see from my SO score that I'm new to the scene. From my work flow so far it *looks* like I need a new tab (visually- that's what I've been doing). Maybe a new process is what I need- I will look into it. Not immediately sure about the differences/use cases atm.

Comment: Yeah, as I say, not familiar with this particular set of tools.  But a terminal tab is really a thing around user (human) interaction.  It sounds like you just want to run your app and your tests in parallel, hence separate processes.  I don't know how you do that in JS (although I'd naively assume that there'd be support for this kind of thing in various test frameworks), but you can achieve this the brute-force way in a shell script by appending `&` to a command (e.g. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-run-command-or-code-in-parallel-in-bash-shell-under-linux-or-unix/)

Comment: Brute force is fine! So, you're saying there's most likely a way to translate everything to a shell script (I think).

Comment: Yes based on what you're saying, I believe so.  I'm not confident it would be idiomatic (so I won't post an answer), but it sounds like it would achieve what you want.  It would basically look something like `run_jest_tests; run_appium_server &; some_loop_that_waits_for_server_to_be_ready; run_ui_tests; kill_server_process` (where `;` corresponds to line breaks).

Comment: Awesome. What is the category of thing I could google for the some_loop part of the sequence? I understand the concept but no idea about implementation. Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: Also not super familiar, but I think you might be looking to spawn a child process from your script. https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Assuming this is an HTTP server, you probably just want a for loop in Bash, along with a `curl` command that tries to hit your server.